# Children.Remove and visiblity collapsed is same behavior?

Tags: wpf, uwp

Is removing the children from the panel and collapsed the children visibility is the same behavior?

I mean, will memory releases when I remove or collapse the children from the panel. I am confused with the concept of visibility(Collapsed) and removing the children from the panel. Can anyone please suggest me and also please explain the performance about this case.

Thanks,
Santhiya

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Visiblity="Collapsed"` then the object will not be removed from memory. But if you remove it using `Children.Remove` then object will be removed from memory.

For more Info see [Optimise you UWP App Without Laziness](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2016/01/18/optimize-your-uwp-app-without-laziness/)

Answer (score 0):

Removing elements from visual tree will free up memory. Setting it to `Collapsed` won't, but events like SizeChanged won't be raised so performance wise it still helps a bit.

In the Creators update there is a new `x:Load` feature available with data binding support, like `<Button x:Load="{x:Bind Show, Mode=OneWay}"/>`. When you set `Show` to False in code, the button will be completely removed from the visual tree.

Comment: You can read more about x:Load from this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-load-attribute